# is there a way to check binary divisibility when the integer is all ones?

Tags: math, primes

Kind of a confusing title so I'll try to explain myself better:
Using pascal's triangle I found that I could check whether a number is a prime using the following equation:

```
boolean isPrime= (2^(x) -2) % x == 0;
```

However, because this operates on powers of 2, it becomes very large very quickly, after a bit of tweaking around I found that I could use the following equation for x>2:

```
boolean isPrime = (2^(x-1) -1 ) % x==0;
```

this isn't changing a lot, however before calculating the mod x the number in binary is all ones (for x=7, it will be 63, or 111111 in binary)

Now my question is if there is a simple way to take advantage of this and create an accurate function to determinate whether a number is a prime.

Comment: You just re-discovered the Fermat test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test Note that 2^(x-1) % x == 1 does not prove primality of x.

Comment: Read up on `modular exponentiation by squaring`. This sort of thing can be done very efficiently (otherwise RSA wouldn't be practical). Fermat's test isn't very good, but ideas related to it lead to the Miller-Rabin test, which is heavily used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simple way to take advantage of the relationship you noticed to create an accurate primality test.

For instance, with *n* = 561 = 3 × 11 × 17, your function incorrectly reports *n* is prime.

You will want to look at [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) and the [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) primality test.